# Nvidia Titan X (Pascal) Tensorflow Windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, nvidia-titan

My Operating System is Windows 10 and I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend on CPU. I want to buy the "Nvidia Titan x (Pascal)" GPU as it is recommended for tensorflow on Nvidia website:

http://www.nvidia.com/object/gpu-accelerated-applications-tensorflow-configurations.html

They recommend Ubuntu 14.04 as the OS.

Does anybody know if I can use Tensorflow on Nvidia Titan x (Pascal) GPU, on my Windows 10 machine?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you find out? Also curious to try the same thing. I just purchased this GPU and wondering if I will be able to get a workflow in Windows 10, or if I will be dual booting and using Ubuntu for tensorflow work.

Comment: I ended up buying the GTX 1080 and it works.